# Gatling for loop inside inject

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am new to Scala and Gatling so bear with me! I want to have a for loop inside inject where I can set how many times I want `atOnceUsers()`instead of just repeating the code x times, but this code is giving me an error so I was wondering if this way is not supported.

```
val numTimes = 3
val scn = scenario("Some scenario").exec(someScenario)

setUp(
    scn.inject(
        for (i <- 1 to numTimes) atOnceUsers(10)
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
)
```

Comment: What is the error? What specific part of the code (line number) is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're close...

.inject takes an array of steps (which a straight 'for' doesn't produce without a 'yield')

what you can do is...

```
scn.inject(
    (1 to numTimes).map(i => atOnceUsers(10))
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Comment: This produces the error `Type mismatch, expected: Int => NotInferedB, actual: AtOnceOpenInjection`

Comment: oops - minor error on my part. I've updated the answer and verified it works