# Gatling loop on multiple commands inside inject

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

My apologies for the redundancy, this is a continuation of my previous question here [Gatling for loop inside inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532943/gatling-for-loop-inside-inject). I realize I did not phrase my question correctly, resulting in a different answer.

I want to have a for loop inside an injection like this, where I can set how many times I want *multiple* commands to be run.

```
scn.inject(
    for (i <- 1 to numTimes){
        atOnceUsers(10),
        nothingFor(10 seconds)
    }
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

I was provided the following answer, which works great if I only have one command I want to run.

```
scn.inject(
    (1 to numTimes).map(i => atOnceUsers(10))
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

However, I want to have multiple commands run, and I am unsure of how to do this. I tried something like this, and got an error saying `Too many arguments for method map(A => B)`.

```
scn.inject(
    (1 to numTimes).map(i => atOnceUsers(10), nothingFor(10 seconds))
).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

I also tried this, and got the error `No implicits found for parameter evidence`

```
def commands() {
    atOnceUsers(10)
    nothingFor(10 seconds)
}

setUp(
    scn.inject(
        (1 to numTimes).map(i => commands())
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group your commands in the loop using List or Seq, but then you need to return an Iterable to `inject` method. `flatMap` helps to merge all intermediate Seqs to one Sequence and thus it becomes Iterable as well.

```
scn.inject( 
  (1 to numTimes).flatMap(i => Seq(atOnceUsers(10), nothingFor(10 seconds)))
)
```

this is what will be constructed as object.

```
res13: io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder = PopulationBuilder(
  ScenarioBuilder("BasicSimulation", List(io.gatling.core.action.builder.PauseBuilder@60a07d77, io.gatling.http.action.sync.HttpRequestActionBuilder@76795a95)),
  InjectionProfile(
    Vector(
      AtOnceInjection(10),
      NothingForInjection(10 seconds),
      AtOnceInjection(10),
      NothingForInjection(10 seconds),
      AtOnceInjection(10),
      NothingForInjection(10 seconds),
      AtOnceInjection(10),
      NothingForInjection(10 seconds),
      AtOnceInjection(10),
      NothingForInjection(10 seconds)
    )
  ),
  Protocols(Map()),
  List(),
  None
)
```